# right continuity set is countable, then left continuity set is countable.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

right continuity set is countable, then left continuity set is countable?

> Let $f: \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$. $D_l(f)$ is the set of all left-continuous points of $f$, $D_r(f)$ is the set of all right-continuous points of $f$. Show that if $D_r(f)$ is countable, then $D_l(f)$ is also countable.

Oh, we only know that continuity points of $f$ forms a $G_\delta$ set. How the left continuity affects right continuity?

Comment: Source, please? I would find this very interesting if this was a true statement.

Comment: It is known  that $D_l(f)\setminus D_r(f)$ is at most countable for any function. [Ref. Real and Abstract Analysis, Hewitt and Stromberg].  Your result follows from this.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer By a Chinese book by Minqiang Zhou.

Comment: Given a function $f(x),$ apply what you are allowed to assume to the function $f(-x)$ and then interpret the result for $f(x).$ For a result much stronger (and known as far ago as 1908) than what @geetha290krm stated, see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/231462/15780).